Global sections of $\mathcal{O}_{X}(D)\otimes\mathcal{I}_{Z}$
I am trying to study the cohomology group $H^{0}(\mathcal{O}_{X}(D)\otimes\mathcal{I}_{Z})$, where $X$ is an algebraic surface complex, $D\in\hbox{Pic}(X)$ is effective and $Z\subset X$ is of codimension $2$. I know that if $\ell(Z)<h^{0}(\mathcal{O}_{X}(D))$, where $\ell(Z)$ is the length of $Z$, then $H^{0}(\mathcal{O}_{X}(D)\otimes\mathcal{I}_{Z})\neq 0$, but and if $\ell(Z)> h^{0}(\mathcal{O}_{X}(D))$, then $h^{0}(\mathcal{O}_{X}(D)\otimes\mathcal{I}_{Z})=0$ necessarily?
Or on the other hand, do they know some vanhishing theorem for $H^{0}(\mathcal{O}_{X}(D)\otimes\mathcal{I}_{Z})$ or that relates $h^{0}(\mathcal{O}_{X}(D)\otimes\mathcal{I}_{Z})$ in terms $h^{0}(\mathcal{O}_{X}(D))$ and $\ell(Z)$?
I will greatly appreciate your help or hints.

Have you considered some simple cases where $X=\mathbb P^2$? The general idea is that if $Z$ is special in some way, there should still be sections even if the length is a bit large.
